# Remove white margin from a page tiles with an image?

Tags: backgrounds

I am trying to tile a page with an image. I have successfully added the image using the command `\TileWallPaper` from the background package, but I am having a problem with a white margin on the left of the paper. Is there a command or a method I can use to shift the tiles to the left so it can cover the whole page?
Here is the code I use:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[cm]{fullpage}
\usepackage[margin=0.3in]{geometry}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%% FOR TILING %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\TileWallPaper{10.0pt}{40.0pt}{tiles.eps}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\newcommand\BackgroundPic{
\put(0,-10){
\parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
\vfill
\centering    \includegraphics[width=18cm,height=20cm,angle=90,keepaspectratio,natwidth=250,natheight=325]{logos/logo.png}
\vfill
}}}
\begin{document}
Anything here
\end{document}
```

And as you can see I also have an image that is centred in the page, but I believe it has nothing to do with the tiles background.

Comment: I could solve this issue, too. Adding

    \setlength{\wpXoffset}{-1cm}

After the tiling commands, solved the issue. I would appreciate it if there is any better solution.

Comment: since you've solved your own problem, perhaps you could add a self-answer, so the question isn't left unanswered.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved in comments